# How to draw a line with Cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to get to grips with Cocos2d by trying to accomplish simple things. At this point, I have a scene, that scene has a background sprite, and a Layer. I'm trying to draw onto the Layer using drawLine. Here's my current attempt.

```
@implementation MyLayer
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil){
        glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);  
        glLineWidth(2.0f);
        CocosNode *line = drawLine(10.0f, 100.0f,400.0f,27.0f);
        [self addChild:line z:1];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Which generates the error "void value not ignored as it ought to be". So obviously I'm doing it wrong, but hopefully you can see my reasoning.

I've also tried this

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil){
        glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);  
        glLineWidth(2.0f);
        drawLine(10.0f, 100.0f,400.0f,27.0f);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Which doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't work either. I realise I'm not understanding something fundamental, but can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the cocos2d [drawPrimitivesTest.m](http://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/454d1753ea73b37dbde4d686a876a542a65e4677/tests/drawPrimitivesTest.m):

```
- (void)draw {
  // ...

  // draw a simple line
  // The default state is:
  // Line Width: 1
  // color: 255,255,255,255 (white, non-transparent)
  // Anti-Aliased
  glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
  ccDrawLine( ccp(0, 0), ccp(s.width, s.height) );

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything when I paste those 2 lines into my HelloWorldLayer.m file. Suggestions?

Comment: Ah, putting them in the layer's draw method, works fine. Thanks!

Comment: GL_LINE_SMOOTH isn't supported in iOS OpenGL 2. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31940

Comment: so this no longer works in 3.0. Investigating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523010/drawing-cocos2d-v3

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I figured it out for anyone who is interested. Here's the code with the comment explaining what to do.

```
@implementation GameLayer
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil){
        // init stuff here      
    }
    return self;
}

// You have to over-ride this method
-(void)draw{
    glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);  
    glLineWidth(2.0f);
    drawLine(10,100,50,79);
}    
@end
```

So I assume, the draw method gets called at every frame.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. 

drawLine(10,100,50,79);

is undefined in CCLayer, won't link the application

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: FYI - this example is out of date for v1.0 of Cocos2D. "drawLine" doesn't exist anymore. Use "ccDrawLine" from the CCDrawingPrimitives with the same arguments.

Comment: To add to Shakakai's comment: also take a look at `ccDrawPoly` in cocos2d if you want to draw more than a single line segment.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use CCRibbon class to draw line with your texture. Here is an example:

First you create CCRibbon with width , image , length , color and fade parameters

```
ccColor4B myColor = ccc4(255, 255, 255, 150);

CCRibbon *ribbon = [CCRibbon ribbonWithWidth:10 image:@"green.png" length:10.0 color:myColor fade:0.7f];
```

Then we add it as a child:

```
[self addChild:ribbon z:8];
```

If you run the application now you will not see anything because you didn’t add any points yet to the CCRibbon so lets add 2 points

```
[ribbon addPointAt:ccp(10,10) width:10];

[ribbon addPointAt:ccp(15,15) width:10];
```

You cannot remove individual points but you can remove the CCRibbon from its parent

```
[self removeChild:ribbon cleanup:YES];
```

Source code from:
http://www.ccsprite.com/cocos2d/using-ccribbon-example.html